# A property of a Array of objects is NULL when before iteration has a value

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am working with Files in TypeScript (Angular 8), So I Encoded the files in Base64 and with the following code:

```
  private async convetTob64(evidences: Array<EvidenceToDisplay>): Promise<Array<EvidenceToDownload>> {
    const results: Array<EvidenceToDownload> = [];
    for (const evidence of evidences) {
      const evidenceToDownload: EvidenceToDownload =  {
        base64: null,
        name: '',
        extension: '',
      };
      const reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onloadend = function() {
        evidenceToDownload.base64 = reader.result;
      };
      reader.readAsDataURL(evidence.file);
      evidenceToDownload.name = evidence.name;
      evidenceToDownload.extension = this.getExtencionFromName(evidence);
      results.push(evidenceToDownload);
    }

    return results;
  }
```

I obtain the result in other method:

```
  public async downloadEvidences() {
            const zip = new JSZip();
            let consecutive = 1;
            const allEvidences: Array<EvidenceToDisplay> = this.mergeEvidenceArray(this.manualEvidences, this.mobilityEvidences);
            const evidencesToDownload: Array<EvidenceToDownload> = await this.convetTob64(allEvidences);
            console.log(evidencesToDownload);
            for (let i = 0; i < evidencesToDownload.length; i++) {
              console.log(evidencesToDownload[i].base64);
              zip.file(EVIDENCE + DASH + consecutive + DOT + evidencesToDownload[i].extension, evidencesToDownload[i].base64,
                 { binary : true, base64: true, compression : 'DEFLATE' });
              consecutive++;
            }
            zip.generateAsync({type: 'blob'}).then(function(blob) {
              FileSaver.saveAs(blob, 'test' + DOT + ZIP);
            });
          }
```

In the first console log of evidencesToDownload I have this result:
[Console log result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GGK7b.png)

But in the console log inside the for iteration I have this result:

[Second console log result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g9L0i.png)

I used to have this problem when I use "array.forEach" but normaly is solve when I change to "normal for" Any one has any idea why is this happen?

I solved by change the way to encode the file to binary instead of base64 like this: (To avoid to use file reader that i think it was the problem).

```
  public async downloadEvidences() {
    const zip = new JSZip();
    let consecutive = 1;
    const allEvidences: Array<EvidenceToDisplay> = this.mergeEvidenceArray(this.manualEvidences, this.mobilityEvidences);
    for (let i = 0; i < allEvidences.length; i++) {
      const extension = this.getExtencionFromName(allEvidences[i]);
      const MIMEType = this.getMIMEtype(extension);
      const blob = new Blob([allEvidences[i].file], { type: MIMEType });
      zip.file(EVIDENCE + DASH + consecutive + DOT + extension, blob,
        { binary : true, compression : 'DEFLATE' });
     consecutive++;
    }
    zip.generateAsync({type: 'blob'}).then(function(blob) {
      FileSaver.saveAs(blob, 'test' + DOT + ZIP);
    });
  }
```

Also this link to read file async helped me: https://simon-schraeder.de/posts/filereader-async/

Comment: There's no `await` in the first method.

Comment: I was thinking that, maybe to put the  `await` in the file `reader.onloaded` I tried but it does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve this by returning array of promises from the function convetTob64.
I added an example below with your modified code.

```js
async function convetTob64(evidences) {
  return Promise.all(evidences.map(evidence => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const evidenceToDownload = {
      base64: null,
      name: '',
      extension: '',
    };
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onloadend = function() {
      evidenceToDownload.base64 = reader.result;
      resolve(evidenceToDownload);
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(evidence);

    evidenceToDownload.name = evidence.name;
    evidenceToDownload.extension = '.someExtension';
  })));
}

async function load(e) {
  const evidences = await convetTob64(Object.values(e.target.files));
  console.log(evidences);

}
```

```html
<input type="file" onchange="load(event)" multiple />
<div id="msg"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks that helps me al lot

Answer (score 0):

The reason why this might happen is that the data is not loaded when you're calling the first `console.log` as `reader.onloadend` is asynchronous.

You should wait for data to complete loading & then only return from the function `convetTob64()`.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved that. Thank for all you take the time to read an help me I changed the way to read the file to binary instead of base64.